# How's exactly Laravel dealing with transaction deadlocks?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, deadlock

Please look at the first comment at the `function handleTransactionException`

> **(framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Concerns/ManagesTransactions.php:61)**

It says following:

> On a deadlock, MySQL rolls back the entire transaction so we can't
>   just retry the query. We have to throw this exception all the way out
>   and let the developer handle it in another way.

Does it comment correct? [Official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/database#database-transactions) says that `Laravel` can dealing with deadlocks automatically and I am supposed to do nothing in that case.

version : `Laravel 5.5`

Comment: It isn't clear what you are asking here.  Are you asking whether the documentation is correct or how to handle deadlocks in laravel?

Comment: @EricHauenstein Sorry for that. I am confused by documentation mismatch between Laravel official website and framework code. It would be great if someone who knows Laravel very well, tells me what information to believe. I has no opportunity to check it by myself.

Answer (score -2):

I was wrong, that comment is related to nested transactions.